# PHP binding data in stored procedure

Tags: php, html

I'm using this kind of data binding in PHP, is it safe?

```
$sql = "CALL registerUsers(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $_usr_code, $_usr_eml, $_usr_name, $_usr_pass, $_fileName,  $_usr_type, $_usr_role);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: There is no context here.  This very short script is asking about _general best practice_, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, as in `$_usr_name` cannot be used to inject SQL commands.

This doesn't mean `$_usr_name` can no longer be a threat. It could, for instance, contain Javascript code and do [a cross-site scripting attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). It is also possible that somewhere else you don't use binding, retrieve the field from the database and insert it in a SQL statement. This would then still allow a SQL-injection attack.

**In short:** *Something can only be said to be safe given the whole context, and you didn't give much context.*

Side note: Apart from safety I have to remark on your choice of variable names. I see that you abbreviate things. For instance, a "user" becomes a "usr", and "password" becomes "pass". Such abbreviations are still understandable, but unnecessary. *Your code doesn't run any faster because you abbreviate things.* Where it gets tricky is with variable names like: `$_usr_eml`. Given the context I surmise that you must be referring to the user's email address. But why let me guess? Why not simply: `$userEmail`? The reason we developed high level programming languages, as opposed to something like assembler, is to make it easier for people to understand the code. By obfuscating the content of your variables you make it harder to understand your code.

Comment: I thought It would be nice to abbreviate variables just like I did. thank you

Comment: @ArtAntonio: I guessed as much: It looks very geeky to have abbreviated variables like this. Variables were abbreviated in the past to save memory. We're living is 2021 now, and memory constraints are no longer an issue.